# Has anyone ever connected Android as a Central to iOS as a Peripheral?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Before you mark this as duplicate, there have been so many questions on SO asking about how to connect Android to iOS over bluetooth. Many of the answers say it isn't possible, or it wasn't possible, or it might be. They are also quite a bit old. This question is about answers from actual practice.

I've done extensive research and found plenty of articles saying it is and isn't possible, but it seems like it should be, especially with Bluetooth Low Energy.

**So here's my simple Yes/No question:** When making an iOS device broadcast as a `Peripheral` using `CoreBluetooth`, have you ever been able to connect an Android device as a `Central` and exchange data?

Comment: It should work - It should be pretty easy to test if you have access to both devices.  You can use LightBlue on iOS to act as a peripheral so you don't even need to write any code...

Comment: See that's the thing. I created two demo apps, one on iOS that can be a peripheral or central, and one for android that acts as a central. (I didn't know about LightBlue, whoops). But the android device would only sometimes pick up on the iPhone. Maybe like 10% of the time. I figured it was my code but I just tried LightBlue with two different BLE apps from the Play Store and I found the same results. It just seems odd it would sometimes work. I figured it would be straight up yes or no. In any case it doesn't seem very reliable.

Comment: I have heard that BLE on Android is pretty flakey but I haven't ever used it myself

Comment: Yeah, especially because when testing with two iOS devices they pick each other up within a second. Oh well.

Comment: I have successfully done it using BLE Utility and/or LightBlue on my iPhone and a custom app on my Android with no problems. So far in my testing BLE has been very reliable and stable on Android 5.0 (Lollipop), and I think most of the stability issues were fixed back in 4.3 or 4.4 when they created a completely new Bluetooth stack for use in Android and did away with the old one

Comment: @Amhurst I have a feeling it comes down to your device. I tried on 4.3, 4.4 and 5.0. Don't get me wrong, it would occasionally work, but not reliably enough to use in prod. Anyway, the amount of users on those versions of android is still too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I wrote a test using an iPhone 5 running 8.1 and a One Plus One running Lollipop. The iPhone advertised a custom service and characteristic, the Android connected to it and retrieved the value of the characteristic.

Interesting observations:

- When the iPhone app was advertising in the foreground the Android could detect it when doing a scan only for the specific service uuid, and it would work every time.
- When the iPhone app was advertising in the background the Android could only detect it if it was doing a generic scan for all devices, it had to connect to every device it could find to see if it contained the correct custom service uuid. And even then it only worked sometimes. I was quite surprised that the iPhone service could be detected at all when it was advertising in the background, considering on the iOS developer site it says peripherals advertising in the background can only be detected by other iOS devices looking specifically for that service.

Comment: do you mean you were using legacy Bluetooth? I am trying to achieve same thing using ble

Comment: @calvin no I used Bluetooth LE. Androids can scan and connect to iOS using Bluetooth LE (at least in the test I did with the devices above)